# Manifest (app.json) not initialized | Expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to implement expo push notification for a chat app so by following the [Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#android)  I reached a part where I need to run the following command : `expo push:android:upload --api-key your-token-here` . So I went and got the token from firebase and after running the command I get an error saying `Manifest (app.json) not initialized`. I guess the problem comes from the fact that I am using a dynamic config (app.config.js). How could I fix it ?

app.config.js

```
import "dotenv/config";

export default {
  expo: {
    name: "XXX",
    slug: "XXX",
    version: "1.0.0",
    scheme: "com.XXXXXXXXX.XXXX",
    orientation: "portrait",
    icon: "./assets/icon.png",
    userInterfaceStyle: "light",
    splash: {
      image: "./assets/splash.png",
      resizeMode: "contain",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ["**/*"],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
    },
    android: {
      package: "com.XXXXXXXXX.XXXX",
      googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json",
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      },
    },
    web: {
      favicon: "./assets/favicon.png",
    },
    extra: {
      apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
      projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      appId: process.env.APP_ID,
      measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
      oneSignalAppId: process.env.ONESIGNAL_APP_ID,
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          photosPermission:
            "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends.",
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you used the dynamic config before this change? It's hard to say for sure, but looking quickly through the config you posted, I believe you are not expected to have the `expo` key in the dynamic config.

Take a look at [config docs](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/), the static configs do have the structure with `expo`:

```
// app.json content
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My app",
    "slug": "my-app"
  }
}
```

But when you look at the dynamic one, everything's flattened to the top level:

```
// app.config.js content
module.exports = {
  "name": "My app",
  "slug": "my-app"
};
```

If it doesn't help, I'd suggest running `expo config` to see the introspected resulting config that Expo sees.